# Solving for $y$ in $(2ye^{\frac{y}{x}}+x)\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x+y$

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Consider $$(2ye^{\frac{y}{x}}+x)\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x+y$$ We are to find a general solution for $y$.

My attempt is to use the substitution $$y=ux$$ which reduces the differential equation to: $$ \frac{2ue^{u}+1}{2-2u^2e^u}du = \frac{dx}{x}$$ But I can't seem to find a way about integrating this expression to get $u$ and hence $y$. I suspect the initial substitution wasn't ideal. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: *I suspect the initial substitution wasn't ideal* - Your suspicions are wrong. The left hand term does possess an elementary antiderivative.

Comment: Interesting. I will try a few more substitutions to see where I can get with it in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i will take it from your last step. you have $$\frac{2ue^{u}+1}{1-u^2e^u}du = \frac{2dx}{x} \tag 1 $$ we can split the numerator $$2ue^u + 1 = 2ue^u + u^2e^u+(1 - u^2e^u) = -\frac{d}{du}\left(1-u^2e^u\right) + (1 - u^2e^u) $$ subbing in $(1),$ we get $$ -\frac1{1-u^2e^u}\frac{d}{du}\left(1-u^2e^u\right) + du  = \frac{2dx}{x}$$ on integration, gives $$u-\ln\left(1-u^2e^u\right) = 2\ln x +C $$

Comment: This is ingenious! Thanks for your time kind sir!

Comment: you are welcome @bigman.